# How to convert a continuous time optimal control problem into to discrete time optimal control problem?

Tags: optimization, approximation, optimal-control, discrete-time

I have an optimal control problem and want to embed it into multi stage optimization problem by first discretizing it into discrete time optimal control problem...

Can I do it by just converting integrations to summations and differential equations to difference equations in both objective functions and constraints of the original optimal control problem?

Comment: As far as I understand, the suboptimality will tend to zero as the sampling time tends to zero.

Comment: Do you have any references regards this?